# Constructing Microsoft Graph with delegate access in .net full framework

Tags: c#, .net, graph, delegates

I am trying to successfully construct the graph client with delegate permissions in .net 4.5 framework. I have literally tried all the ways I have found on the internet, and all of them are not working.
I have my application registered in azure ad with delegate permissions, but have not had any luck constructing it. Here is the latest that I have tried:

```
    //private string[] _scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    //private string[] _scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All" };
    //private readonly string[] _scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };
    private readonly string[] _scopes = new string[] { "User.Read.All" };
 
    public GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(ClaimsIdentity userIdentity) =>
        new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async requestMessage =>
            {

                // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
                var accessToken = await _authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();

                // Append the access token to the request
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);


            }));
}

    public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
    {

        try
        {
         
           var result = await _app.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();
            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(new Error
            {
                Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                Message = "Caller needs to authenticate. Unable to retrieve the access token silently."
            });
        }
    }
```

Can I get a full code snipet to construct the Microsoft graph client properly for delegate permission for a full framework web application?

Answer (score 0):

I found a valid example finally that had the proper setup for delegate permissions for microsoft graph:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start?appID=383cb18f-fedb-4165-a82f-e9ed354d124c&appName=My%20ASP.NET%20App&redirectUrl=https://localhost:44375/&platform=option-dotnet